A trapped wire can be untangled with a weird movement
What does this trapped wire have to do with topology ?? Can this situation be coded in some equation ?? The video is shown here : https://youtu.be/lTtSENVPVa4?si=O8hsS4D-btrNsYm8

You must know that the term "topology" in this context isn't the same as "general topology" with open sets, neighborhoods, etc... In this Wikipedia article, both meanings are under a same overhead.

The order goes top left $= 1$ (configuration right before the unkotting occurs), top right $= 2$, bottom left $= 3$ and bottom right $ = 4$. The relevance to topology is unknotting a curve about a line given the restriction that you can't pass the endpoints under the line. This is an isotopy of the curve which can be relative to the endpoints.

